# KeyStores need SecretKey object, Java JCE provider has NO KeyFactory support to turn RAW AES Keys into SecretKey objects

Tags: aes, keystore, secret-key

In researching what KeyStore I would use (JCEKS or PKCS12) I came to the conclusion that the KeyStore interface of Java JRE8 (and before e.g. 7) uses the SecretKey objects as input and output arguments to store SecretKey entries in the KeyStore (which makes sense).

However, while according this [document of Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyFactory) there should be support for the AES algorithm in the SecretKeyFactory, there isn't.
As [this Oracle Bug report](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7022467) shows others have detected this problem in Windows and Linux but someone that clearly doesn't use KeyStores preferred to remove AES from the supported list for SecretKeyFactory rather then implementing an AES KeyFactory.

As a consequence one can use NON of the 4 Java implemented KeyStores including both that I mentioned above in a rich way. One is FORCED to store SecretKey objects when they are just generated because the AES algorithm is supported for the KeyGenerator, but one can NOT do something with the key and later, from the RAW key "factor" a SecretKey by setting up the correct SecretKeySpec with a Keyfactory.

As, probably many, I use the SecretKeySpec object to work around this for the other functions (Mac, Cipher, etc) because it has a getEncoded() method.

Is there someone that knows a trick to turn a SecretKeySpec object into a SecretKey object other then using a SecretKeyFactory. The STUPID thing about all this is that broken algorithms such as single DES are supported but the Oracle person in charge finds it, I quote "mistake" to have an AES KeyFactory.

Can this problem be circumvented with BouncyCastle for instance. I use it for the Cipher part and Secure Random seeding so I might as well use it as a KeyFactory for AES. However, it also refuses AES as an algorithm for KeyFactory. Possibly the the SPI filters it out already.

It may also be that I didn't completely grasp WHY the presence of an AES KeyFactory  is a mistake and that there possibly is an alternative way to set symmetric keys to the KeyStore with SecretKeySpec object, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Even though its name ends `Spec` and is located in `javax.crypto.spec`, `SecretKeySpec` *also* `implements javax.crypto.SecretKey` and thus can be used to create a `SecretKeyEntry`. Only a JCEKS (or BKS) can *contain* a SecretKeyEntry, not JKS *or* PKCS12.

Comment: Thanks Dave. So what you suggest is keep using SecretKeySpec because it implements a SecretKey anyway and then pass SecretKeySpec objects to the /KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry constructors/methods. BTW it totally escaped my attention that SKS implemented SecretKey.

Comment: Exactly. Create the `SecretKeySpec` but when you need a `SecretKey` just use it.

Comment: Note that the reason why the bug was closed is *absolutely stupid*. The AES key factory makes perfect sense for hardware tokens and is very easy to implement in software. What you now get is that you need to implement a separate software and hardware method for generating keys. Somebody at Oracle should be given some hints with a clue stick.